Telegram，Do a shake function on your phone，How to use an accelerometer to achieve
Please help me, how to use an Accelerometer to shake it
I want to achieve that when I shake my phone, the data increases and vibrates continuously. The data will continue to increase and vibrate continuously
Here is the code I am currently using. Although it responds when shaken, it is not smooth
if (window.Telegram?.WebApp?.Accelerometer) {
  window.Telegram.WebApp.Accelerometer
    .start({
      frequency: 90
    }, (started) => {
      if (started) {
        console.log('ok');
        this.checkAccelerometer();
      } else {
        console.log('no');
      }
    });
}
checkAccelerometer() {
  if (!window.Telegram?.WebApp?.Accelerometer?.isStarted) {
    this.isShaking = false;
    return;
  }

  const currentTime = new Date().getTime();
  const x = window.Telegram.WebApp.Accelerometer.x;
  const y = window.Telegram.WebApp.Accelerometer.y;
  const z = window.Telegram.WebApp.Accelerometer.z;

  if ((currentTime - this.lastUpdate) > this.timeThreshold) {
    const diffTime = currentTime - this.lastUpdate;
    const diffX = this.lastX - x;
    const diffY = this.lastY - y;
    const diffZ = this.lastZ - z;


    const speed = Math.sqrt(diffX * diffX + diffY * diffY + diffZ * diffZ) / diffTime * 10000;


    if (speed < this.minThreshold) {
      if (this.isShaking) {
        this.isShaking = false;
        console.log('stop');
      }
    } else if (speed > this.shakeThreshold &&
      currentTime - this.lastShakeTime > this.shakeCooldown) {
      this.onShake();
      this.lastShakeTime = currentTime;
    }

    this.lastUpdate = currentTime;
    this.lastX = x;
    this.lastY = y;
    this.lastZ = z;
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(this.checkAccelerometer);
},


There is no code in your question
